# pip install tesserocr fails by giving error in Windows "Tesseract library not found in LIBPATH: []"

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, pytesser

I am trying to install tesserocr and I am getting the below error when I do pip install tesserocr
Here is the setup which I have done. Want to know what is the issue and how can I resolve it ?

1. Downloaded the latest from https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki
2. Set the path for Tesseract-OCR in the environment variables.

Error below
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -mportlib-metadata (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
Collecting tesserocr
Using cached tesserocr-2.6.1.tar.gz (58 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [50 lines of output]
Failed to extract tesseract version number from: tesseract v5.3.1.20230401

```
   leptonica-1.83.1
    libgif 5.2.1 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 2.1.4) : libpng 1.6.39 : libtiff 4.5.0 : zlib 1.2.13 : libwebp 1.3.0 : libopenjp2 2.5.0

   Found AVX2

   Found AVX

   Found FMA

   Found SSE4.1

   Found libarchive 3.6.2 zlib/1.2.13 liblzma/5.2.9 bz2lib/1.0.8 liblz4/1.9.4 libzstd/1.5.2

   Found libcurl/8.0.1 Schannel zlib/1.2.13 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.4 libidn2/2.3.4 libpsl/0.21.2 (+libidn2/2.3.3) libssh2/1.10.0
  Supporting tesseract v3.04.00
  Tesseract major version 3
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 243, in get_build_args
    File "<string>", line 99, in package_config
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
      self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
      hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-89658jrl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-89658jrl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-89658jrl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-89658jrl\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 329, in <module>
    File "<string>", line 260, in make_extension
    File "<string>", line 252, in get_build_args
    File "<string>", line 216, in get_tesseract_version
  RuntimeError: Tesseract library not found in LIBPATH: []
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Answer (score 1):

Follow instruction on [tesserocr for windows](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr/blob/master/Windows.build.md) or install prebuild wheel from https://github.com/simonflueckiger/tesserocr-windows_build/releases

Comment: Tried this. But it is erroring out with error "WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -mportlib-metadata (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tesserocr-2.6.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tesserocr-2.6.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64"

Comment: How did you "try that"? Showing an error message without steps to reproduce the problem is useless

Comment: Resolved the error and found a work around for the same. Thank you. Means a lot